# Cannot setup qemu networking with user mode

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm just trying to get access to the internet from my centos-7 guest. Host: Ubuntu 18.04

I read some basic guides and run qemu with:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -drive file=centos7-disk.qcow2,index=0,media=disk -drive file=centos7-disk.raw,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -m 1024 -cpu host -netdev user,id=n1 -device virtio-net,netdev=n1 -serial stdio
```

In the guest i get an eth0 interface with an ip 172.20.189.16/16.
But when i try something like

> curl [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

i get stuck and then:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com; Unknown error

I've also tried to run it with **-device e1000,netdev=n1** instead of **-device virtio-net,netdev=n1**.
In this case i don't even get the eth0 interface and curl fails immediately with the same error.

*The guest runs on 3.10.0-1160.el7 kernel with no changes in config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534184/network-not-working-in-a-qemu-kvm-virtual-machine-running-arch-linux).

The point is that i have centos-7 minimal that requires some network settings being up manually.
For the workaround i needed just run dhclient manually:

```
dhclient ens3
```

ens3 - virtual NIC in case of mine.

To make the change permanent i did:

```
nmcli con mod ens3 connection.autoconnect yes
```